Did Mariabell end up punishing Bleublanc?
in The Legend of Heroes: Trails to Azure, Bleublanc does one of his scavenger hunts with the SSS by stealing Mariabell's Rosenberg Dolls. when they are returned Mariabell laments that she can't punish him by wishing he had never been born for stealing them.
 
following the events of Trails to Azure, Mariabell accepted The Grandmaster's offer to fill Weissmann's spot as the Third Anguis of Ouroboros. since she joined Ouroboros as one of it's leaders did Mariabell end up punishing Bleublanc for stealing her dolls?

Are we now accepting video game questions as well, like, really becoming an ACG (animation, comics and games) StackExchange community? Isn't this better asked on Arqade?

@Gao unless it's changed story based questions on JRPGs are allowed here and i ask here rather than Arqade because i think i'd more likely find those who might have read/watched/listened to the supplementary material like the Northern War anime or the Drama CDs

Ah, forgot about the rules as I see screenshots of video games and immediately thought otherwise. That makes sense: we allow questions about Final Fantasy and Touhou afterall. It's rare that we get this kind of questions so I am just asking for confirmation.
